# MikTeX Update Wizard 2.9.6100 cannot connect anymore

Tags: miktex, update

I run MikTeX on a 32-bit Windows XP SP3 (Italian) environment. Everything always worked fine until my latest update to 2.9.6100 release. As usual, at first, Update Wizard got its main binaries (of course, an updated version of Update Wizard itself among them) and the installation went right. However, from then on I could not get any further updated package because I keep on receiving the error message

```
Sorry but something went wrong: SSL connect error
```

This error window is followed by a different one, with the message

```
Windows API Error 0
```

My log file lists the following rows (I omitted time info):

```
INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6100)
INFO  FileCopyPage - 
INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: SSL connect error
INFO  FileCopyPage - 
INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: Windows API error 0: Operazione completata.
INFO  FileCopyPage -
```

Please, is there anyone who can help? As far as I can judge, my LaTeX installation still works perfectly but now I am unable to get any updated package, including a possible fix for this behavior.

Comment: It looks like my Internet connection is working properly. I also noticed that MikTeX Settings utility succeeds in getting the Repository list. My feeling is that there may exist a communication problem (a protocol one, I guess) between Update Wizard and the specific remote server it tries to connect with. I can directly ping any repository without any single problem.